# Acer Chromebook 15 no sound with Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: sound, alsa, chromebook

I have an Acer Chromebook 15 (CB3-532) with a flashed bios running Ubuntu 20.10, I know it's not LTS but 20.04 this didn't work either so I thought I would give it a try. I've tried looking for sound drivers but I know those don't exist. I also tried changing asound.state to asound.state_old like some people have said so the system rebuilds it. I tried pasting this `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` into the config file. I also just unzipped the stock recovery ChromeOS image for this Chromebook to use it's asound.state because I know ChromeOS runs on Linux.
Nothing I have done could get sound working on this Ubuntu install. Can someone please help me, it's my only computer at the moment.[image: Dummy output sound only]

If it helps: `noah@noah-laptop1:~$ cat /proc/version Linux version 5.8.0-25-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-022) (gcc (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.35.1) #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:30:38 UTC 2020`
Also, I'm running the version of Gnome Ubuntu came with, no modifications.